# IN-BIOS Emulated PS/2 mouse responding NACK to commands

Tags: x86, operating-system, driver, mouse, bios

**Background:**

I use barmetal code for [i8042 PS/2 controller](http://wiki.osdev.org/%228042%22_PS/2_Controller) i.e. keyboard and mouse driver. The mouse and keyboard is connected through USB interface, but due to [USB Legacy support](https://superuser.com/questions/303365/what-does-legacy-usb-mouse-support-in-a-bios-mean) USB key and mouse emulated as PS/2 devices by BIOS. This question is about mouse, so let's focus on it.

By default a Movement packet which sent by mouse to controller consists from 3 bytes:

```
          Bit 7      Bit 6      Bit 5        Bit 4      Bit 3         Bit 2      Bit 1         Bit 0
Byte 1  Y overflow  X overflow  Y sign bit  X sign bit  Always 1    Middle Btn  Right Btn   Left Btn
Byte 2                                X movement
Byte 3                                Y movement
```

There is an Extension called `Intellimouse Extensions`, which needed to make wheel working. This extension could be actiavated at the init step as following:

```
Get mouse id (mouse will respond with ID==0 as non Intellimouse)
Set sample rate 200
Set sample rate 100
Set sample rate 80
Get mouse id (if this mouse support Intellimouse Extensions mouse will respond with ID==3)
```

After this kind of a setup the mouse will send 4 bytes packet extended with information about Z axis movement (wheel). This is an example of such init from Linux kernel:

```
 572 /*
 573  * IntelliMouse magic init.
 574  */
 575 static int intellimouse_detect(struct psmouse *psmouse, bool set_properties)
 576 {
 577         struct ps2dev *ps2dev = &psmouse->ps2dev;
 578         unsigned char param[2];
 579 
 580         param[0] = 200;
 581         ps2_command(ps2dev, param, PSMOUSE_CMD_SETRATE);
 582         param[0] = 100;
 583         ps2_command(ps2dev, param, PSMOUSE_CMD_SETRATE);
 584         param[0] =  80;
 585         ps2_command(ps2dev, param, PSMOUSE_CMD_SETRATE);
 586         ps2_command(ps2dev, param, PSMOUSE_CMD_GETID);
 587 
 588         if (param[0] != 3)
 589                 return -1;
 590 
 591         if (set_properties) {
 592                 __set_bit(BTN_MIDDLE, psmouse->dev->keybit);
 593                 __set_bit(REL_WHEEL, psmouse->dev->relbit);
 594 
 595                 if (!psmouse->vendor)
 596                         psmouse->vendor = "Generic";
 597                 if (!psmouse->name)
 598                         psmouse->name = "Wheel Mouse";
 599                 psmouse->pktsize = 4;
 600         }
 601 
 602         return 0;
 603 }
```

**Problem:**

The problem is that I have one x86_64 target, where this commands (changing sample rate, getting mouse id) are responding with 0xFE code which means NACK. Where on other several x86_64 targets and in qemu it works fine and i recieve 0xFA (ACK) code and then reading appropriate values from data port. As a result I can't enable wheel support.

**Questions:**

1.) Because legacy USB support is used the PS/2 device behaviour is emulated, i guess the BIOS could just not emulate whole behaviour. Is this possible? Does it mean I can't use wheel mouse when using legacy USB support?

2.) What are other reasons why device may answering NACK to any of this commands?

Comment: A mouse can answer NACK to a setSampleRate command if the frequency requested is not supported. Can you plug a mouse that you know had answered correctly to those command into the offending machine? If you still receive NACKs then it must be the SMBIOS not translating them.

Comment: It answers NACK to all commands i send to the mouse, actually i tried dummy loop for i =0;  i< 0xff; i++ . I can't plug real mouse because there is no ps/2 interface. Only usb legacy mode is available

Comment: @Margaret Bloom you can post this comment as an answer if you would like to.